# Value of an unbounded definite integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Evaluate the integration :

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-(2x^{2}+2xy+2y^{2})}dxdy$$

The function is even about $x$ & $y$. So we can write, $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-(2x^{2}+2xy+2y^{2})}dxdy=2\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-(2x^{2}+2xy+2y^{2})}dxdy$$.

But now , how I will proceed it?

Comment: **Hint:** $2x^{2}+2xy+2y^{2}$ is a positive definite quadratic form and symmetric matrices can be unitarly diagonalized. Make a suitable change of variable.

Comment: you could write the exponent as $\vec{x}^tM\vec{x}$, with a $2\times2$ matrix $M=((2,1)(1,2))$. Now diagonalize this matrix by an transformation $D=SMS^{-1}$ and use that the Jacobian $\det(S)$ is just one. Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take the integral 
$$
I=\int_R\int_R dxdy e^{-\frac{1}{2}\vec{x}^t M \vec{x}} 
$$
where $M$ is a positiv definite and symmetric $2\times2$ Matrix. In this case we can find an orthogonal transformation $S$ that fullfills $S^{t}MS=D$ where D is a diagonal matrix. Using $S^tS=1$ we can rewrite the exponent as $\underbrace{\vec{x}^tS}_{\vec{\zeta}^t}\underbrace{S^tMS}_{D}\underbrace{S^t\vec{x}}_{\vec{\zeta}}$, where the entries of $D$ are the two eigenvalues of $M$. The measure transforms as $dxdy \rightarrow \underbrace{|\det(S)|}_{1}d\zeta_1d\zeta_2$ so the whole integral reads:
$$
I=\int_R\int_R d\zeta_1d\zeta_2 e^{-\frac{1}{2}\vec{\zeta}^t D \vec{\zeta}}= \int_R\int_R d\zeta_1d\zeta_2 e^{-\frac{1}{2}\zeta_1 \lambda_1 \zeta_1}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\zeta_2 \lambda_2 \zeta_2}
$$

Which is just the product of two independent Gaussian integrals. It follows that I is just given by
$$
I=\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{\lambda_1}}\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{\lambda_2}}=\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{\det(M)}} 
$$

Which is in your case $(\lambda_1=2,\lambda_1=6)$

$$
\pi \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}
$$

This method is generalizable to non symmetric positive definite $n\times n$ matirx by using the decomposition $2M=(M+M^t)+(M-M^t)$.

Edit: Correct Eigenvalues used

Comment: Very laborious....

Comment: but general....

Comment: Yes.....Obviously

Comment: It's not laborious at all, you just need to calculate the eigenvalues of a 2x2 (in this case) matrix.

Comment: In fact you don't need the eigenvalues but only the determinant (which is easier to obtain).

Comment: it is a very nice way! Only thing, I think you should elaborate on the fact of why the domain of integration does not change with the transformation

Comment: @Ant it's due to the fact that our orthogonal transformation is just a rotation in the plane. Thinking of the measure as an infinitesimal volume element, it's clear that it doesn’t change under this kind of transformation.

Comment: @tired I'm talking about why the new extremes of integration for $\zeta_1$ and $\zeta_2$ are the same as for $x, y$

Comment: the norm of our vectors is unchanged under rotations :) $<\zeta,\zeta>=<Sx,Sx>=<x,x>$

Comment: @tired I'm sorry, maybe I am not being very clear :) If I want to integrate over a circle, I can make the change $x = \rho \cos \theta$, $y = \rho \sin \theta$. Now the integral changes, I multiply for the determinant of the jacobian, $\rho$ (which roughly gives me how much the infinitesimal area element changes) **but** I'm also changing the domain over which I'm integrating; namely, it is no more the circle of radius $R$ but the rectangle $[0, 2\pi] \times [0, R]$. In this case the domain does not change, right? It is not apparent to me why is it so :-)

Comment: Very nice proof. It is the generalization of such type of  exponential integrals.

Answer (score 4):

If you substitute $x=u+v$ and $y=u-v$ you get $$x^2+xy+y^2 = (u+v)^2+(u+v)(u-v)+(u-v)^2 = 3u^2+v^2.$$ In order to do the change of variables you will need to compute the Jacobian for this change of variables. In this case $u=\frac{x+y}{2}$ and $v=\frac{x-y}{2}$ and the Jacobian matrix is given by $$\left[ \begin{array}{cc}1/2 & 1/2\\1/2 &-1/2\end{array}\right]$$ and its determinant is $-1/4-1/4=-1/2$.

Now you can rewrite the integral as $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-2(3u^2)-2v^2} |-1/2| dudv = 1/2 \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-2(3u^2)}du \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-2v^2}dv.$$ Now if you know the integral formula for a Gaussian, you can plug that in to these two integrals. Recall that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2} dx = \sqrt{\pi}$.

Comment: I have a problem in your work about the limit of $v$. How it remains the same?

Comment: $u$ and $v$ both go from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ just as $x$ and $y$ do. You can see this by looking at particular segments of the plane. For instance if $x=0$ and $y \to \infty$ we have $v = -y/2 \to -\infty$. If $y=0$ and $x\to\infty$ we have $v = x/2 \to \infty$. What we have really did is re-express the coordinates on the plane in terms of the vectors $(1,1)$ and $(1,-1)$. This is called a change of basis in linear algebra.

Comment: Would be nice if you could explain how you figured out what to substitute for $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Generally you are looking for some other combination of terms that will eliminate that cross term (the $xy$) in your equation. For most problems like this a substitution as in $x=au+bv$ and $y=cu+dv$ will work. This is what @tired is doing in his answer by using matrices. It's really the same as picking a combination of $a,b,c,d$. Usually just picking the substitution I did above will work out. If it doesn't then tweak it a bit until it does.

Comment: More explicitly replacing $x$ and $y$ as I said leads to $$(au+bv)^2 + (au+bv)(cu+dv) + (cu+dv)^2$$ $$=(a^2+ac+c^2)u^2+(b^2+bd+d^2)v^2 + (2ab+ad+bc+2cd)uv$$ and your goal is to pick $a,b,c,d$ so that $(2ab+ad+bc+2cd)$ is zero.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**: $$2x^2+2xy+2y^2=2\bigl(x+\tfrac{1}{2}y\bigr)^2+\frac{3}{2}y^2.$$ Now use change of variable $u=\sqrt{2}(x+y/2)$ and $v=\sqrt{3/2}y$

Answer (score -1):

Assuming $x$ and $y$ are real, Wolfram gives the indefinite integral as
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2} e^{-2y^{2}} \sqrt{e^{y^{2}}} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} erf\left(\frac{2x+y}{\sqrt{2}}\right)
\end{equation}

Comment: I know the answer ...But I want to know the procedure